# On select event with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code which will contain around 30 cities, for now it contains only 4

```
<div class="container">
  <select id="Test1" name="type">
    <option value="Constanta">Constanta</option>
    <option value="Bucuresti">Bucuresti</option>
    <option value="Brasov">Brasov</option>
    <option value="Iasi">Iasi</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="map-container">
    <div class="map-container-v2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the JS code

```
$('#Test1').change(function(){
  var text = '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d182321.71624603283!2d25.954554063943487!3d44.43774014324156!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x40b1f93abf3cad4f%3A0xac0632e37c9ca628!2sBucharest!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sro!4v1490040907737" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  $('.map-container-v2').html( text );
});
```

Basically what I want to do is that every time I select a city another map is displayed. How should I proceed ?

Comment: There's a different `iframe` for each map?

Comment: Why not update an iframe... You should also be appending not using html. $('.map-container-v2').append(text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `data-...` attribute for each entry, containing its map URL:

```js
$('#Test1').change(function(){
  var clicked = $('#Test1 option:selected');
  
  var ifr = $("<iframe width=600 height=450 frameborder=0 style='border:0' allowfullscreen></iframe>").
  attr('src', clicked.data('map'));

  $('.map-container-v2').empty().append(ifr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <select id="Test1" name="type">
    <option value="Constanta" data-map="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d91559.90078575464!2d28.55929951397897!3d44.18137956197751!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x40bae54a64345229%3A0x637be1cd3e654850!2sConstan%C8%9Ba%2C+Romania!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1490042803339">Constanta</option>
    <option value="Bucuresti" data-map="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d182321.71624603283!2d25.954554063943487!3d44.43774014324156!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x40b1f93abf3cad4f%3A0xac0632e37c9ca628!2sBucharest!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sro!4v1490040907737">Bucuresti</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="map-container">
    <div class="map-container-v2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Now I understand it better !

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it that way.

```
$('#Test1').change(function(){
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();
    var map;

    switch(selectedOption) {
        case 'Constanta':
            map = '<iframe src="link to map"></ifame>';
            break;
        case 'Bucuresti':
            map = '<iframe src="link to map"></ifame>';
            break;
        case 'Brasov':
            map = '<iframe src="link to map"></ifame>';
            break;
        case 'Iasi':
            map = '<iframe src="link to map"></ifame>';
            break;
    }

    $('.map-container-v2').html( map );
});
```

Comment: Thanks , I will try this as well sometime